# Why am I getting - No value accessor for '' - error whenever I am using a custom UI input component in Angular2 RC 1?

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="employee.dob" ></datepicker>
```

Above is a ng2-bootstrap UI component I am using for my application. I am getting the error as mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. You question should contain the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of the datepicker component? What version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap  Thanks in advance! I am using RC 1 for angular2...

Comment: Just for your additional information, I am getting the error wheneve I try to bind my model to a third party UI component...

Comment: Might be an issue with your configuration. I'd try to remove `npm_modules` and reinstall them.

Comment: so should i just delete all the npm_modules and install them again??

Comment: That was my suggestion. It was mentioned quite often already that this fixed such issues where the code looked perfectly valid but still didn't work.

Comment: I don't know why, didn't workout for me, sorry!

Comment: Maybe a Plunker for us to reproduce? The "new" button provides an up-to-date Angular2 template.

Comment: Sorry but didn't get ya!

Comment: In Plunker there is a "new" button that allows to select an Angular2 TS template. It's a fully set up minimal running Angular2 application where you only need to add to reproduce your problem.